# Not connected (cURL error 7: Failed to connect to my.elementor.com port 443: Connection refused) Wordpress - elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Good afternoon, someone could help me with this problem. I have my local wordpress website that the item is working properly and is connected to the library. When I migrated it to my hosting site it doesn't work in the elementor / System Information part I get this message `Not connected (cURL error 7: Error connecting to my.elementor.com port 443: Connection refused)` The truth that I cannot solve it and I would like you to support me in finding the cause and being able to give a solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NAsu.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered this before but you can try deactivating(Not deleting) the current elementor plugin you have and then downloading a new one from wordpress. Then extracting the Zip file to public-html/wp-content/plugins